# How should dynamic Kubernetes/OpenShift DNS resolution be configured?

Tags: docker, dns, kubernetes, containers, openshift

I'm unable to find relevant information on this, which is why I'm asking the question here.

Instead of using `/etc/hosts` which is a hacky solution for resolving Kubernetes container names to their service IP addresses, what would the best method be to automatically or dynamically map new Kubernetes pods to their service IPs?

I've heard using `/etc/resolv.conf` is one such method, but was unable to find exactly how that file should be configured for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenShift it deploys with an internal DNS. When you create a *Service* object it will automatically have its service name, setup as a hostname in the internal DNS, with it mapping to the IP address of the service.

Further the label selectors on the service are matched against labels on *Pods*, the IP addresses of the pods will be associated as an endpoint for that service and internal network setup so that connection to the service IP directly, or after DNS lookup by hostname (service name), will route connection through to one of the pods.

So all of this is done for you automatically and you don't need to do anything. The service object is even created for you automatically if you are using `oc new-app` to deploy applications in OpenShift.

Comment: That's the information I've found on it, but if that's the case, why am I still having errors when I attempt to connect using hostnames? When I attempt to connect to my PostgreSQL container using psql, I get the following error: "psql: could not translate host name "ms-primary" to address: Name or service not known"

Comment: If you have installed OpenShift yourself, it would suggest the setup isn't working properly. What OpenShift cluster is this? Something you set up yourself, Minishift, oc cluster up, OpenShift Online? If Minishift or oc cluster up, what underlying operating system are you using?

Comment: oc cluster up on CentOS 7, on a VirtualBox VM is my current environment. For Kubernetes (which is also having the issue), it has consistently also not worked in this regard through Minikube, kubectl + oc cluster up, or kubeadm.

Comment: Did you follow setup instructions for ``oc cluster up`` around firewall setup? https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#linux

Comment: Yes, followed all instructions.