# WAR Deployment in OpenShift

Tags: java, mysql, openshift, war

I have a Java .war file which i need to host with mysql DB.
Can anyone help with the exact procedure to host it in OpenShift?
And how to make the connection from app to DB?

Comment: How are you building it? Maven?

Comment: And which version of openshift are you using and where is it running (eg Openshift.com)?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821903/329496 which pointa out that if you use an openshift template to add mysql to your project then openshift will add the mysql service to the internal DNS and your java app should be able to connect using the the internal DNS name and the port shown for the mysql service on the openshift Web console.

Comment: Building in Maven
  Trying to deploy in openshift.com its version 2

Comment: Openshift V2? thats been closed down?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Maven to build the app and you are running it on OpenShift Online then you can use the built-in Java template. Use "Add to Project" and select "Java" and select "Open JDK". It asks you for a name and a git url to your code. You should start out by using the git url it suggests to see how their sample code is built by maven and run on Openshift.

If you don't like the way that their code builds/runs then I wrote a Java demo that builds a WAR then tells Openshift to run the WAR using `tomcat7-maven-plugin`. The POM file has an "openshift" maven profile that uses tomcat7 to run the WAR that you can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/simon_massey/thinbus-srp-spring-demo/src/290f176f53ee2cbc145e70de1cdcd66b8c85e4d0/pom.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#pom.xml-264). That profile is enabled by default on the standard Openshift OpenJDK template.

Once you have your Java code running it is recommended that you deploy your MySQL database as a separate pod/service in your project. That way you can scale your Java pods independently of your database. Once again you can use the built-in Openshift Online templates. Select "Add to Project", "Data Stores", "MySQL (Persistent)" and use the defaults.

The final piece is how to connect your Java app to your database. Here you are in very safe hands with OpenShift. As we see [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/additional_concepts/networking.html#openshift-dns) OpenShift has as internal DNS that publishes the IP of any service. When I ran the mysql template it crated as service "mysql". This is then published in DNS as `<service>.<pod_namespace>.svc.cluster.local`. The pod_namespace is the openshift project. So in my case my demo code OpenShift project is called 
`thinbus-srp-spring-demo` so the Java pod can connect to the mysql service using the DNS name `mysql.thinbus-srp-spring-demo.svc.cluster.local`. So I can configure that as the database hostname in a JDBC connection string.

These instructions are how to use the mouse and it assumes you are using an OpenShift instance with the OpanJDK and MySql templates installed. You don't actually need any of those. You can create your own custom template that has the whole solution. That is quite an advanced topic so I won't cover that in this answer.